# backup windows folders with rsync from a linux server

Tags: linux, windows, rsync

Windows now has a build in openssh server, so we can use rsync to backup folders on windows pcs too.
Problem is, that if I try to

```
rsync --relative -aqz --numeric-ids --delete-after -e 'ssh' 's2@black:C:\Users\s2\.gnupg' black
```

from a linux server, I end up with a local directory structure that looks like this:

```
black/
└── C:\Users\s2\.gnupg
    ├── crls.d
    │   └── DIR.txt
    ├── gpg-agent.conf
  [...]
    └── trustdb.gpg
```

so the root folder is a single folder named `C:\Users\s2\.gnupg`, and not three foldes like `Users/s2/.gnupg`.
Is there a way to translate the windows path to a linux path so the backup makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

you could merge the dir afterwards with

```
./script black
```

the script uses GNU find `-print0` to loop over C: and create all directories, `mv` all files and delete old directories. only problem directories lose metadata like xattrs (but can easily overcome with few lines code for `chown` `chcon` etc)

script

```
find "$@" -depth -type d -iname 'C:\\*' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' dir || [ "$dir" ]
  do
    path="${dir%/*}"
    dir="${dir##*/}"
    mkdir -p "$path/${dir//\\//}"
    find "$path/$dir" -maxdepth 1 -not -type d -exec mv {} "$path/${dir//\\//}" +
    rmdir "$path/$dir"
done
```

---

**edit:**

for mixed paths you need a little more code for merging. you can use `cp -l` instead `mv` for moving files via hard-links. metadata is preserved

script

```
#!/bin/bash
# or sh supporting read -d

# random name
tmp="${0##*/}_$(date '+%s')_tmp~"

# search for windows drive letters 'C:\' in 'black'
find -L "$@" -type d -iname '[A-Z]:\\*' -print0 | sort -z | while IFS= read -r -d '' dir || [ "$dir" ]
  do
    printf "'%s' -> " "$dir"

    # resolve symlinks
    dir="$(realpath "$dir")"

    path="${dir%/*}"
    dir="${dir##*/}"
    win="${dir%\\*}"
    nix="${dir##*\\}"

    printf "'%s'\n" "${dir//\\//}"

    # create linux directories
    mkdir -p "$path/${dir//\\//}"

    # move childs windows -> linux preserving metadata (via hard-links)
    find "$path/$dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \( -exec cp -abflPx {} "$path/${dir//\\//}" \; -a -exec rm -r {} \; \)

    # rename parent windows -> linux
    mkdir -p "$path/$tmp"
    mv "$path/$dir" "$path/$tmp/$nix"

    # copy parent metadata
    rsync -aAX "$path/$tmp/$nix" "$path/${win//\\//}"

    # delete windows directories
    rmdir "$path/$tmp/$nix" "$path/$tmp"
done
```

unfortunately it's much slower because `find -exec \;` and some unneccessary `sort` and `echo`

Answer (score -1):

you need to mount `/mnt/c/` first
or use cwrsync

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Why would mounting the `C` drive help?  What is cwrsync and how does one use it?

Comment: https://thedatafrog.com/en/articles/backup-rsync-windows-wsl

Comment: self explaining - once mounted you can access paths with regular slash / i don't have Windows 10 to test but the link gives some instructions. i can copy & paste that or just delete that answer